# Problem with root fs

Tags: linux, grub, initramfs

I am trying to make my own linux. After I compiled it, I moved bzImage and initramfs to the `/boot` directory so the directory structure looks like:
/
boot
-bzImage
-initrd.img

When i then tried to make it into a ISO, it worked:
I built it using: 
`grub-mkrescue -o a.iso .`
`qemu-system-x86_64 -cdrom a.iso`
After booting the qemu it showed this(after bunch of linux loading logs):
[image]

I dont know what to do..

grub.cfg if important:

```
set timeout=10
menuentry "Boot to Shell" {
    set root=(cd)
    linux /boot/bzImage root=/dev/ram0
    initrd /initrd.img
}
```

EDIT: When I set `/dev/sr0` as device address, and rootwait, it does this error (unlike anything else with rootwait so the drive must be getting detected by itself, but the file is not loadable[i think])

Comment: I think it's kinda impossible for anyone to tell what you have missed exactly when it's a custom distro and no one even knows e.g. what you use as the early init and what's the content of your initramfs. We also can't tell whether the kernel was builtin with all the necessary driver for your desired machine and setup either.

Comment: `this error (unlike anything else` also it's unclear what you are talking about here. What's the exact difference of using `/dev/sr0`? And why were you even trying `/dev/ram0` instead?

Comment: Initramfs - Generated from the default thing(so containing /dev and /root, /root containg console) linux having default settings, only setting being changed is 64->32bit kernel. /dev/sr0 difference with /dev/ram0 is that /dev/sr0 contains the file but the system cannot mount it(for some weird reason) the error is meant as the system not being able to mount the root fs.